# How to catch errors and best practices?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm performing various tasks on an eloquent model.

e.g.

Flight Repository

```
function store($request){

    $flight = new Flight;

    $flight->name = $request->name;

    $flight->save();
}
```

This method is called from a controller:

```
public function store(FlightRepository $flight, $request){

    $flight->store($request);

}
```

How should one approach potential errors? try/catch? Where should it be placed in the controller or repository? What would I catch anyway, what exception type?

Comment: You should throw exception from within the repository as its common for all the controllers, i.e. whenever a controller calls a repository method your repository will throw an Exception instead of again and again throwing it from multiple controllers

Comment: how would I throw the exception? Wouldn't eloquent throw one anyway say if something was wrong? Then should i catch this in the controller? What type would it be?

Comment: Are you ever going to need to swap implementation (Eloquent for something else?) just curious, @SaumyaRastogi has the point, throw up in Repositories, and catch in implementation if you want to catch exceptions globally head to `Exceptions/Handler.php` (Like ModelNotFound...)

Comment: It would just be eloquent. Don't want to catch globally, thanks for info tho.So what would I need to implement in the repository? Nothing? Just a try/catch in controller? Catching what exception?

Comment: So if you are never going to swap it why do you want to do repository pattern in first place. Yes catch exceptions in controller. If you are serious about rep. pattern, catch all eloquent exceptions in repository (so repository is "true package" which you can take and do copy-paste in another project) and throw your custom Exceptions further to controller and catch that, or catch in repository and return true/false (or model/null). Yet again, "true repository" does not return Eloquent Model, but StdObject or array or something... I would skip repo pattern and just use eloquent without facades.

Comment: Interesting - I like the idea of the true package. So I would try/catch the database write in the repository. Then return a custom exception or return null/false etc? What exception would I catch in the repository?

Comment: Depends; as far as I know take a look at this https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent.html so ModelNotFoundException and MassAssignmentException. In many of my projects I tend to globally catch ModelNotFoundException and just show 404 page. In your case you need to think this through, what are your needs and who is going to use your code etc. do search about when to use repository pattern (in regard to Laravel). Remember use exceptions in exceptional cases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Laravel 5.0 and above,

All the Exceptions thrown in any part of the Laravel App, the exceptions are catched inside the `report()` method of `Exception/Handler.php` file, like this:

**UPDATED**

Your Repo should throw an Exception like this:

```
class CustomRepository extends Repository
{
    public function repoMethod($id)
    {
      $model = Model::find($id);

      // Throw your custom exception here ...
      if(!$model) {
          throw new CustomException("My Custom Message");
      }
    }
}
```

And your `Handler` should handle the `CustomException` like this:

```
/**
 * Report or log an exception.
 *
 * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return void
 */
public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    // Handle your exceptions here...
    if($exception instanceof CustomException)
       return view('your_desired_view')->with('message' => $exception->getMessage());
    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting - but I'd want to catch in a controller and then perhaps show a custom error. Not sure what to catch or if errors would be automatically thrown from the repository or if I would have to throw myself?

Comment: You can also create your own Exceptions, and then catch them inside the report method with your custom message, let me update my answer in a while!

Comment: Thanks for the update. What would I catch in my repo to throw the custom message? Would I catch anything or just check if store was true/false? if false throw custom exception?

Comment: No you don't need to catch any exception, if any exception occurs it would be catched automatically inside `Handler.php` file which automatically breaks your code flow...

Comment: So why would I throw new CustomException("My Custom Message"); in my repo then? What would cause this? Why wouldn't I try/catch something in the repo and then throw the custom message?

Comment: Try and catching exception should only be done at one place, to avoid repetition of your code. Thats why you just throw an exception wherever you want, and catch all of them inside Handler!

Comment: I think your missing the question - what would cause me to throw an exception in my repository?

Comment: It can be anything, like if you try to find a model object but you failed to find the particular column, you just throw the exception, and catch that into `Handler.php`, see my updated repo in the answer above!